# Using mongodb $lookup on big documents is slow

Tags: performance, mongodb, lookup

I have users_users document with 966.628 entries and orders_orders with 1.419.081 (and above 14.000.000 entries inside orders).

I need to retrieve user's data based on multiple filters (location, birthday, nb orders, nb products bought, etc.) but it never ends. I'm new with mongodb so I probably do bad things and need to learn.

```
db.users_users.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        locale: {
            $in: ["fr_FR", "fr_BE"]
        },
        "users_addresses.country_iso2": "FR",
        mobile: {
            $ne: null
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "orders_orders",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "id_user",
        as: "orders"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$orders"
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "lastname": {
            $first: "$lastname"
        },
        "firstname": {
            $first: "$firstname"
        },
        "email": {
            $first: "$email"
        },
        "date_birth": {
            $first: "$date_birth"
        },
        "locale": {
            $first: "$locale"
        },
        "nb_orders": {
            $sum: 1
        },
        "order_total": {
            $sum: "$orders.tax_inclusive_amount"
        },
        "last_order": {
            $max: "$orders.date_creation"
        },
        "entries": {
            $push: "$orders.entries"
        },
        "countries": {
            $addToSet: "$users_addresses.id_country"
        },
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$entries"
}, {
    $unwind: "$entries"
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "lastname": {
            $first: "$lastname"
        },
        "firstname": {
            $first: "$firstname"
        },
        "email": {
            $first: "$email"
        },
        "date_birth": {
            $first: "$date_birth"
        },
        "locale": {
            $first: "$locale"
        },
        "nb_orders": {
            $first: "$nb_orders"
        },
        "order_total": {
            $first: "$order_total"
        },
        "last_order": {
            $first: "$last_order"
        },
        "countries": {
            $first: "$countries"
        },
        "nb_entries": {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        nb_orders: {
            $gt: 1
        },
        nb_entries: {
            $gt: 10
        }
    }
}])
```

**EDIT:** 
Indexes, documents and output as requested

**users_users indexes**

```
> db.users_users.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "pre_mongified_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "pre_mongified_id_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "email" : 1
        },
        "name" : "email_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "date_birth" : 1
        },
        "name" : "date_birth_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "mobile" : 1
        },
        "name" : "mobile_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "locale" : 1
        },
        "name" : "locale_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "users_addresses.postal_code" : 1
        },
        "name" : "users_addresses.postal_code_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "users_addresses.city" : 1
        },
        "name" : "users_addresses.city_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "users_addresses.country_iso2" : 1
        },
        "name" : "users_addresses.country_iso2_1",
        "ns" : "elf.users_users"
    }
]
```

**orders_orders indexes**

```
> db.orders_orders.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "elf.orders_orders"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "pre_mongified_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "pre_mongified_id_1",
        "ns" : "elf.orders_orders"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "id_user" : 1
        },
        "name" : "id_user_1",
        "ns" : "elf.orders_orders"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "entries.id_target" : 1,
            "entries.type" : 1
        },
        "name" : "entries.id_target_1_entries.type_1",
        "ns" : "elf.orders_orders",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "number" : 1
        },
        "name" : "number_1",
        "ns" : "elf.orders_orders"
    }
]
```

**users_users sample**

```
> db.users_users.find().limit(2).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c46f6eae6f960fb6f59107"),
    "id_civilitytitle" : 2,
    "date_creation" : ISODate("2008-09-05T18:17:42Z"),
    "date_update" : null,
    "firstname" : "xxx",
    "lastname" : "YYY",
    "email" : "xxx@xxx.fr",
    "phone" : "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "mobile" : null,
    "fax" : "",
    "disabled" : false,
    "confirmed" : true,
    "date_birth" : null,
    "locale" : "fr_FR",
    "users_addresses" : [
        {
            "id_country" : ObjectId("56c43401ae6f960fb6000396"),
            "name" : "Adresse",
            "fullname" : "YYY xxx",
            "address1" : "xxx",
            "address2" : null,
            "city" : "xxx",
            "postal_code" : "11610",
            "country_iso2" : "FR"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c46f6eae6f960fb6f59108"),
    "id_civilitytitle" : 2,
    "date_creation" : ISODate("2008-09-06T14:38:59Z"),
    "date_update" : null,
    "firstname" : "aaa",
    "lastname" : zzz",
    "email" : "xxx@xxx.fr",
    "phone" : "xx xx xx xx xx",
    "mobile" : null,
    "fax" : "",
    "disabled" : false,
    "confirmed" : true,
    "date_birth" : null,
    "locale" : "fr_FR",
    "users_addresses" : [
        {
            "id_country" : ObjectId("56c43401ae6f960fb6000396"),
            "name" : "Adresse",
            "fullname" : "aaa zzz",
            "address1" : "xxx",
            "address2" : null,
            "city" : "xxx",
            "postal_code" : "59180",
            "country_iso2" : "FR"
        }
    ]
}
```

**orders_orders sample**

```
> db.orders_orders.find().skip(5).limit(2).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c46ccfae6f960fb6dfe9c3"),
    "id_user" : ObjectId("56c46f6eae6f960fb6f59109"),
    "date_creation" : ISODate("2008-09-09T08:21:56Z"),
    "number" : "c000026",
    "tax_inclusive_amount" : 10,
    "shipping_fees" : 5.95,
    "paid" : null,
    "cancelled" : "cancelled",
    "locale" : null,
    "from_mobile" : false,
    "entries" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c4340dae6f960fb60008b5"),
            "id_order" : ObjectId("56c46ccfae6f960fb6dfe9c3"),
            "id_target" : 58,
            "type" : "reference",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "reference" : "#4203",
            "name" : "XXX",
            "tax_inclusive_price_unit" : 1,
            "tax_inclusive_price_total" : 1,
            "tax_rates" : "a:1:{i:0;O:38:\"Catalog_Model_References_Container_Tax\":5:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000rate\";d:0.196000000000000007549516567451064474880695343017578125;s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000name\";s:6:\"19.60%\";s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000type\";s:32:\"cbf1c9560e4d3dbae5d65339aefed7b0\";s:13:\"\u0000*\u0000proportion\";d:1;s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000value\";N;}}",
            "weight" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c4340dae6f960fb60008be"),
            "id_order" : ObjectId("56c46ccfae6f960fb6dfe9c3"),
            "id_target" : 247,
            "type" : "reference",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "reference" : "#1711",
            "name" : "XXX",
            "tax_inclusive_price_unit" : 1,
            "tax_inclusive_price_total" : 1,
            "tax_rates" : "a:1:{i:0;O:38:\"Catalog_Model_References_Container_Tax\":5:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000rate\";d:0.196000000000000007549516567451064474880695343017578125;s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000name\";s:6:\"19.60%\";s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000type\";s:32:\"cbf1c9560e4d3dbae5d65339aefed7b0\";s:13:\"\u0000*\u0000proportion\";d:1;s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000value\";N;}}",
            "weight" : null
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c46ccfae6f960fb6dfe9c4"),
    "id_user" : ObjectId("56c46f6eae6f960fb6f5911d"),
    "date_creation" : ISODate("2008-09-09T12:32:40Z"),
    "number" : "c000027",
    "tax_inclusive_amount" : 15,
    "shipping_fees" : 5.95,
    "paid" : "paid",
    "cancelled" : null,
    "locale" : null,
    "from_mobile" : false,
    "entries" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c4340dae6f960fb60008bf"),
            "id_order" : ObjectId("56c46ccfae6f960fb6dfe9c4"),
            "id_target" : 105,
            "type" : "reference",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "reference" : "#9011",
            "name" : "XXX",
            "tax_inclusive_price_unit" : 1,
            "tax_inclusive_price_total" : 1,
            "tax_rates" : "a:1:{i:0;O:38:\"Catalog_Model_References_Container_Tax\":5:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000rate\";d:0.196000000000000007549516567451064474880695343017578125;s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000name\";s:6:\"19.60%\";s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000type\";s:32:\"cbf1c9560e4d3dbae5d65339aefed7b0\";s:13:\"\u0000*\u0000proportion\";d:1;s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000value\";N;}}",
            "weight" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("56c435b0ae6f960fb614c240"),
            "id_order" : ObjectId("56c46ccfae6f960fb6dfe9c4"),
            "id_target" : 364,
            "type" : "reference",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "reference" : "#1710",
            "name" : "xxx",
            "tax_inclusive_price_unit" : 1,
            "tax_inclusive_price_total" : 1,
            "tax_rates" : "a:1:{i:0;O:38:\"Catalog_Model_References_Container_Tax\":5:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000rate\";d:0.196000000000000007549516567451064474880695343017578125;s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000name\";s:6:\"19.60%\";s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000type\";s:32:\"cbf1c9560e4d3dbae5d65339aefed7b0\";s:13:\"\u0000*\u0000proportion\";d:1;s:8:\"\u0000*\u0000value\";N;}}",
            "weight" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

**expected output**

Multiple data from users_users for each lines (firstname, lastname, email, birth_date, locale, ...)

Comment: Please provide sample documents and expected output. Furthermore, please provide the indices of the affected collections. Add this information by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35507764/edit)

Comment: Do you have an index on the join fields: `_id` and `id_user`?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg information added as requested

Comment: @Jaco yes as seen with my edit

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the query is slow is because further queries on the documents retrieved with the `$lookup` operator do not use indexes.

`$max: "$orders.date_creation"` in particular won't be indexed so it will do a full scan to retrieve this.

Comment: Yes. But solution is needed, not the reasons.